# How to execute different code based on the device manufacturers?

Tags: java, android, build

I want to execute different codes for different device manufacturers.

I know I can do it by using `Build.MODEL` and then check which model is that user using.

But the main problem is suppose

`LG Optimus Zone 3` would return `VS425PP`

`Samsung J7 Prime` would return `J7 Prime`

`Samsung J7 2016 Edition` would return `SM-J710F`

`ZTE Z798BL` would return `Z798BL`

In the above cases is would be difficult to find out which manufacturer does that device belong to.

Can Any one please help with this.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: @JoeC My App would be preloaded to different phones/manufacturers. So I need to provide the users with different features/credits based on the manufacturer.

Comment: "My App would be preloaded to different phones/manufacturers" -- then you will know what those devices will return for `Build.MANUFACTURER`, `Build.MODEL`, and so forth. After all, you are going to test your app on that hardware, to confirm that your app works properly on that hardware. So, you see what that hardware returns, and make your decisions based on that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank will find out that whether it returns the needed value from the phone to which my app will be preloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just read it from android.os.Build.Manufacturer or android.os.Build.Brand?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html?hl=ja

Comment: Thank You very much. But will all Samsung device return `Samsung` value as the manufacturer, or will all the  LG Device return  `LG` as the value?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to return what you need. The best way of finding out is trying it yourself.

Comment: Thank Have tried it out. Working fine with all of my test devices. Thanks Once Again.